# Inserting HTML elements on rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a view with a bunch of elements in it.One of them (a div) is shown depending of a value that changes inside a select_tag (also within the same page).

I'm getting the selected ID from the select_tag element

```
$('#some_id').on('change',function(){
    //$(this).val()
})
```

but then just don't know how to fetch the object and check for one of its properties and that way know if I should show the div or not?.

I thought of sending that id to the server...do whatever I need over there and then come back to the view and try something like this

```
<% if some_condition %>
 <div>
  ...
 </div>
<% end %>
```

This (of course) might not be the way.I'd be glad to understand how this happens

Comment: Does showing/hiding the div have anything related to any business logic that is present in the server, or does it only depend on the selected option's value ?

Answer (score 0):

You way of doing it after getting some data from the server `onChange` of the `select` would  work. You might also consider this approach.

But if you could pre-populate the divs and add a class or some other attribute it with which you could relate to the chosen option in the select field, then you can prevent the server call entirely.

```
<div class="opt1Val selectOptsDiv"> </div>
<div class="opt2Val selectOptsDiv"> </div>
<div class="opt3Val selectOptsDiv"> </div>
```

hide all these divs initially with `css` `display: none;`.

```
$('#some_id').on('change',function(){
  var selectedOptionVal = $(this).find("option:selected).val();
  $("." + selectedOptionVal).show();
})
```

But I guess you would be able to do this if the showing and hiding of the div's depend only on the selected option value and do not have to go through some other processing at the server end.

Comment: Well...they (in my case only one) cannot be all hidden at page loading because when I get the page (on edit) the select_tag gets populated.This means that after the form is being rendered I need to check right away the current value --> $('#some_id').val(). Now, the ID it gives me belongs to a model which holds some other important params for me.What should be the correct way of calling an action from my javascript that could allow me to find an object by the ID I got and save it in a instance variable that could be used as a condition?

Comment: Does the div you are showing or hiding contain the select tag also ? If not, if the options contain those id in their value then on document.ready, the select will be already populated and you could show one single div which matches the current selected option's val.

Comment: you could use AJAX to make a call to the server on document.ready and on change and then achieve your desired result anyways.

Comment: No,the select_tag is not within the div I want to disappear.Honestly,I don't know why is this giving me such a hard time.Yeah,as you said I have the values on load.Let's say [[name1,1],[name2,2]] and onChange I get any of those IDs but I don't know whether to show the DIV or not cause first need to check on another attr before deciding that.Another attr that should be found through that ID.Sorry for overloading you.

Comment: You could pass the selected option val to the server and then based on the response show/hide the other divs or construct them dynamically as you wrote in the question.

Comment: Yeah,I get that value.It's just that it would be easier to see a similar example in order to know how it works cause I've never implemented it before.